# Consider migrating all questions tagged Android to android SE

Tags: support, migration, android

There are a few dozen questions in Super User tagged [android](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android).  Most of these have been closed as off-topic.  They should be migrated to the relevant SE.

Answer (score 7):

Although BloodPhilia is right, moderators can migrate to any site, and have done this where relevant.

However, moving a question that is more than two weeks old, and where the original poster has never come back, doesn't really add value to a new beta site.

If an OP wants a question moved we will be more than happy to do so.

Flag the question for moderator attention where relevant and we will review on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! :D Another thing learned today!

Answer (score 3):

https://android.stackexchange.com/ is currently still in open beta, migration paths will only be created AFTER a stackexchange website comes out of open beta into a permanent website. Therefore, no migration at this moment can be committed simply because the path is not there yet.

If we migrate all questions that involve Android to Android.SE and Android.SE would not make it into a permanent website, all questions migrated there will be lost. (As in, only archived)